# Moving from C array to std::map <int, val> operator `-` gotcha

Tags: c++, c

I had a C style array of some values. I needed it to be a map for memory economy (not allocate all at once and keep but allocate as needed)... It can be made into a set or in futher optimization a vector. But I got on one painfull gotcha: `val * v; auto val_index = v - val_collection` used to give item id... now such code will not compile. will it in std::vector case?

Comment: In what way does `val * - val_collection` give an item ID?

Comment: here by id was meant item index in the collection

Comment: @sftrabbit I think you should read that as "a pointer to a value minus the array's base address", i.e. computing an array member's index by pointer arithmetic.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I entirely understand what you are doing, but I think you can achieve what you want with [`std::map::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin) and [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

Comment: what do you want to *achieve*? a `map` and a C-style array are two completely different things. You can't just change single lines to do "the same" with such different data structures.

Answer (score 2):

`std::distance` can give you the distance from the beginning of a container (or other sequence):

```
std::vector<val>::iterator v = whatever();
size_t val_index = std::distance(val_collection.begin(), v);
```

For random-access containers (including `vector`, but not `map`), you could also use `-` if you like:

```
size_t val_index = v - val_collection.begin();
```

Comment: +1 for being able to parse OP and infer what it was that she was really after.

Comment: @HappyGrenKidNaps: "index = item - collection" was almost self-describing, except for the ".begin()" missing.